# How to streamline my code - UIImage imageNamed:

Tags: iphone, uiimage

More iPhone stuff...
Does anyone know how I can trim this code down. So I don't have to write every single image.

Thanks a lot

```
bMon01.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0001.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0002.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0003.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0004.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0005.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0006.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0007.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0008.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0009.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0010.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0011.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0012.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0013.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0014.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0015.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0016.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0017.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0018.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0019.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0020.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0021.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0022.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0023.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0024.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"mon01_0025.png"], nil];
```

Comment: As a future note to anybody reading this: If you're starting out writing iPhone code, any code for that matter, and you're repeating yourself almost at all, or something seems tedious, there's a 100% chance that you can make the computer do that work for you.

Answer (score 8):

Will this help:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) 
  [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mon01_%04d.png",i]]];

bMon01.animationImages = array;
```